# How to configure timer service in websphere liberty profile

Tags: ejb-3.1, websphere-liberty

I want to configure a timerservice in Websphere Liberty Profile.
I defined an EJB as follows, however it does not fire on the Application start.
I am using

```
<feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
```

Note: I cannot use ejb3.2 for the current project.

```
@Singleton
public class TimerEvery5Sec {
    private static int i = 0;

    @Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void doWork(){
        System.out.println("timer: " + i++);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCons(){
        System.out.println("TimerEvery5Sec intiated");
    }

    public String callMe(){
        return "TimerEvery5Sec - called";
    }
}
```

Does liberty profile for ejbLite3-1 support timers?
if so, what should be done to register it in the server.xml

Comment: Any reason why you cant use ejbLite-3.2? Latest Liberty supports that and timers (both persistent and non persistent).

Answer (score 2):

The Liberty profile feature ejbLite-3.1 does not support timers. Non-persistent timers were not added to the 'Lite' feature set in the EJB specification until version 3.2.